# Need to show count on same records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a query in which i have added a join for data and it is showing expected data.Along with that I need one more column..

**Orignal Query**

```
select 
f.trackingnumber,f.wrkflw_task_id,f.record_number,f.current_task_ind, d.wrkflw_stage_name, D.WRKFLW_STAGE_NAME_DESC as CURRENT_STAGE_NAME
from clm.rpt_d_contract_workflow_task D
join clm.rpt_f_contract_event f on (f.wrkflw_task_id=d.wrkflw_task_id)
where 
f.current_task_ind='Y' and 
d.wrkflw_stage_task_ind = 'S' and trackingnumber in ('20830836');
```

**Orignal Result**
[image]

Required Additional column

```
TRACKINGNUMBER   COUNT
20830836       2
20830836       2
```

Here **count** is the total number of same TRACKINGNUMBER

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL <> Microsoft SQL Server. Please specify your RDBMS.

Comment: Sorry guys just update Tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `COUNT(*) OVER(...)`:

```
SELECT "current columns here", 
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY TRACKINGNUMBER) "COUNT"
.....
```

Comment: In MySQL? Are you sure it supports windowed functions (except MySQL 8.x development series)?

Comment: @lad2025 Ah, didn't notice that tag, just saw the "sql-server" one. But you are right, it won't work in mysql

Comment: @Lamak Oracle so it will work, just rename `[COUNT]` to `"COUNT"` :)

Comment: @lad2025 yeah, just what I was doing. Funny that in the end wasn't either mysql nor SQL Server

Comment: @ErKKChopra you just need to add the `COUNT(*).....` as one more column in your `select`

Comment: @lad2025 though now I'm kind of offended that op's just dismissing me. Maybe you write the answer ;)

Comment: @Lamak Just copy rest of his query :)

Comment: @ErKKChopra ?, it depends on where you want it to appear in the select. But you just need to add it as another column of the select, I'm not really following the problem